# use SKU in stead of Product_name in URL

Tags: magento-1, url-rewrite, sku

i want to rewrite the url of product from

> www.example.com/product-name.html

To

> www.example.com/SKU.html

Someone can help me? I am beginner of magento.but i have too many existing products.

Comment: Wait you can any url key on product management.. That can be product name also can be sku

Comment: no ,sku is just like a Code,product name is the title of the page.it must be a sentence.

Comment: just  put sku  field value at url key filed.You donot need any customization

Comment: should i do it in file url.php?

Comment: Whatever that will. You just need to put that on url_key field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an extension,its free and easy to use.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/30396/s/custom-product-urls-seo/